# ros-indigo-rviz fails to buil

Tags: ros, python, rviz, build, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm try to install rviz in archlinux by using yaourt. I run `yaourt -S ros-indigo-rviz` and everything seems to be all right until the very end of the compile, and error occured:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../devel/lib/rviz/two_render_widgets
[100%] Built target two_render_widgets
Scanning dependencies of target librviz_sip
[100%] Running SIP generator for rviz_sip Python bindings...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 50, in <module>
    config = Configuration()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 19, in __init__
    ['qmake', '-query'], env=env, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
src/python_bindings/sip/CMakeFiles/librviz_sip.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'devel/bin/sip/rviz_sip/Makefile' failed
make[2]: *** [devel/bin/sip/rviz_sip/Makefile] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3152: recipe for target 'src/python_bindings/sip/CMakeFiles/librviz_sip.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/python_bindings/sip/CMakeFiles/librviz_sip.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build ros-indigo-rviz.
```

It may be because of the python version, I have installed python3.4.3, python2.7 in the system.

Could someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217575/ros-indigo-rviz-fails-to-buil/) by [cptlsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/23857/cptlsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-13**:
Is `qmake` on your path?

**Comment by [cptlsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/23857/cptlsk/) on 2015-09-14**:
Hi William, thanks for your reply! I'm new to ROS so I don't know how to check the path. Could you please explain more details of your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`qmake` is the executable that it is trying to run, based on `['qmake', '-query'], ...` being passed to subprocess, and if it is not on the `PATH` then you could get the error you're getting: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, see: http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0